# Update sales order grid on order saving - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I added a new attribute on **order entity** :

```
$salesSetup->addAttribute(Order::ENTITY, "shipping_date", [
    'type'     => "date",
    'label'    => "Shipping date",
    'input'    => "text",
    'user_defined' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'visible' => true
  ]);
```

and display it on the sales order grid

> view/adminhtml/uicomponent/sales_order_grid.xml

:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="shipping_date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Date</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

And when I'm saving a new order I would like to populate the `sales_order_grid` so I added this code in

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="shipping_date" xsi:type="string">sales_order.shipping_date</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

The issue is when I'm saving the order it creates a blank line in `sales_order_grid` table with only the shipping date filled, all other fields are NULL, where is my mistake ?

Comment: I followed this way, but all the value are updating to the sales_order_grid table except the custom column value. is there any other code is missing?

Comment: Also when i add the above virtualtype my page will be blank

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you forget to add the `type` on your `virtualType` in **`di.xml`**
Update your `virtualType` like this :

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="shipping_date" xsi:type="string">sales_order.shipping_date</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: how to insert custom value on sales_order_grid during this insertion?